# how to find number of processes running particular command in python

Tags: python

The output of

```
ps uaxw | egrep 'kms' | grep -v 'grep'
```

yields:

```
user1  8148  0.0  0.0 128988  3916 pts/8    S+   18:34   0:00 kms 
user2 11782  0.7  0.3 653568 56564 pts/14   Sl+  20:29   0:01 kms
```

Clearly two processes running the program. I want to store this number (2 here) as a variable. Any suggestions on how to do this in python?

I tried the following:

```
procs = subprocess.check_output("ps uaxw | egrep 'kmns' |grep -v 'grep'",shell=True)
```

But i get the following (I think when the jobs are not currently running, so number of processes running the jobs is zero):

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>      File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 573, in
>   check_output
>       raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output) subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'ps uaxw | egrep 'kmns' |grep
>   -v 'grep'' returned non-zero exit status 1

How do I get around this?

Btw, here is the function I wrote to detect if my system was busy (which means if the number of cpus > total installed, and if load avg > 0.9 per cpu):

```
def busy():
    import subprocess
    output = subprocess.check_output("uptime", shell=False)
    words = output.split()
    sys.stderr.write("%s\n"%(output)) 
    procs = subprocess.check_output("ps uaxw | egrep '(kmns)' | grep -v 'grep'", shell=True)
    kmns_wrds = procs.split("\n")
    wrds=words[9]
    ldavg=float(wrds.strip(','))+0.8
    sys.stderr.write("%s %s\n"%(ldavg,len(kmns_wrds)))
    return max(ldavg, len(kmns_wrds)) > ncpus
```

The above is called by:

```
def wait_til_free(myseconds):
    while busy():
        import time
        import sys
        time.sleep(myseconds)
        """ sys.stderr.write("Waiting %s seconds\n"%(myseconds)) """
```

which basically tells the system to wait while all cpus are taken.

Any suggestions?

Many thanks!

Comment: Why are you using `egrep 'kms'` instead of just `grep kms`? Also, why are you passing flags to `ps` whose only purpose is to add extra information to the output when you don't care about the output?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're going to do this all with a big shell command, just add the `-c` argument to [`grep`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/grep.html), so it gives you a count of lines instead of the actual lines:

```
$ ps uaxw |grep python |grep -v grep
abarnert         1028   0.0  0.3  2529488  55252 s000  S+    9:46PM   0:02.80 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/ipython3
abarnert         9639   0.0  0.1  2512928  19228 s002  T     3:06PM   0:00.40 /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python /usr/local/bin/ipython2
$
$ ps uaxw |grep python |grep -c -v grep
2
```

Of course you could make this more complicated by adding a `| wc -l` to the end, or by counting the lines in Python, but why?

---

Alternatively, why even involve the shell? You can search within Python just as easily as you can run `grep`—and then you don't have the problem that you've accidentally created a `grep` process that `ps` will repeat as matching your search and then need to `grep -v` it back out:

```
procs = subprocess.check_output(['ps', 'uaxw']).splitlines()
kms_procs = [proc for proc in procs if 'kms' in proc]
count = len(kms_procs)
```

---

Or, even more simply, don't ask `ps` to give you a whole bunch of information that you don't want and then figure out how to ignore it, just ask for the information you want:

```
procs = subprocess.check_output(['ps', '-a', '-c', '-ocomm=']).splitlines()
count = procs.count('kms')
```

---

Or, even more more simplierly, install [`psutil`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil) and don't even try to run subprocesses and parse their output:

```
count = sum(1 for proc in psutil.process_iter() if proc.name() == 'kms')
```

Comment: Thanks! What if there are multiple commands I am looking for, such as suppose I have another command called AdjR and another called BHI. etc? I guess i could put them all in the if command, but is there another way? That is why I was using egrep, etc.

Comment: @user3236841: Each of these different solutions can be adapted pretty easily. For example, in the first one, you'd replace the `grep kms`; for the penultimate one, `sum(procs.count(p) for p in ('kms', 'AdjR', 'BHI'))`; for the last one, `… if proc.name() in ('kms', 'AdjR', 'BHI')`; etc.

Comment: Thanks! I decided to stick with subprocess (is there an advantage to psutil?) so I went ahead with option 2. I modified it and it appears to work (no error). Thanks!

Comment: @user3236841: Well, doing things directly in Python is generally simpler than using a subprocess and parsing its output. Plus, it's portable to any platform `psutil` works on (which includes Windows, old versions of Solaris, etc.) instead of depending on having a `ps` tool that handles the mix of old-style and new-style arguments you used, an `egrep` tool, etc. And you'll get better error handling if something goes wrong, because you don't have all those intermediate layers to try to parse the information out of.

Comment: @user3236841: Of course the disadvantage is that you add an external dependency (not usually a problem if you're going to put your tool on PyPI or deploy it to a bunch of machines that you control, but it can be a problem in other cases obviously), and you have to learn `psutil` (which is pretty simple and well-documented, but if you already know `ps` like the back of your hand, nothing is easier to learn than what you already learned:).

Comment: Btw, trying out the psutil, I did the following:      procs = ["run_kmeans", "AdjRand", "BHI", "Diag", "ProAgree", "VarInf", "R"]                                           kmns_wrds = sum(1 for proc in psutil.process_iter() if proc.name() in procs)

Comment: But I get  the following error:    kmns_wrds = sum(1 for proc in psutil.process_iter() if proc.name() in procs)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable   -- what am i doing wrong?

Comment: @user3236841: Maybe you or I have an old version of `psutil`, and `name` is a property rather than a method in your version. Just debug this like any other code: break the expression up into smaller pieces and see which one is actually failing, then use help() or read the docs to see if you're using it wrong.

Comment: I think that is true: even the examples on the documentation fail. I am using python-psutil-1.2.1-5.fc21.x86_64 from the Fedora 21 repos.

Comment: Actually, I wanted to ask another question: for option number 2 above, the one involving kms_procs, how do I handle multiple arguments? Example: 'kms', 'zathura', "R", etc are the process names I am checking for. Should I just loop the kms_procs in there and increment the count inside the loop or is there a better, more elegant way? Thanks!

Comment: @user3236841: You can put the loop inside the other one instead of outside: `procs = [proc for proc in procs if any(name in proc for name in ('kms', 'zathura', 'R')]`. But that's just moving it around; the logic is the same. Unless you either want to parse the proc names so they'll be `==` instead of just `in` (in which case you can use a `set`), I don't see any way around that.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to simulate pipes you can use Popen:

```
p1 = Popen(["ps", "uaxw"], stdout=PIPE)
p2 = Popen(["grep", 'kms'], stdout=PIPE, stdin=p1.stdout)
p1.stdout.close()

out,_ = p2.communicate()
print(len(out.splitlines()))
```

Or use [pgrep](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pgrep) if it is available:

```
count  = check_output(["pgrep", "-c", "kms"])
```

You may get different output from both as pgrep only gets the executable's names but so will ps -aux vs ps -a.

Comment: Sure, but if he wants to do this in Python instead of a big shell pipeline, he doesn't even need `grep` (and therefore doesn't need the extra `grep -v grep` at the end…), he can just search each line or the whole output of `ps` from within Python.

Comment: @abarnert, to be honest I did not really pay much attention to  the command, I just prefer using Popen when piping  but yes you are right.

Comment: I don't think `pgrep` is guaranteed by POSIX. But it might be guaranteed by whatever OS he's using (I think Linux, FreeBSD, and OS X all have it in the core userland?), so maybe that's a good improvement anyway.

Comment: @abarnert, yes, not available on all but if it is, it will make life easier.

Comment: From a quick check, it's part of FreeBSD base, the "standard" it's part of is NetBSD 1.6+, and it's based on the function from Solaris 7. And GNU includes it in core, and it's based on the function from Solaris 7. So, I think it's pretty close to available everywhere that he's likely to care about.